# Написал код. Бот должен приветствовать пользователей и прощаться с ними в личных сообщениях

Tags: python, discord.py

Пишу своего дискорд Бота, он должен приветствовать пользователей и прощаться с ними в личных сообщениях. После запуска кода выводит ошибку:

> AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Bot'

подскажите, что делать.

```
bot = discord.Bot( intents = discord.Intents().all )
channelIDS = 812680242812420111

@bot.event
async def on_member_join( member ):
    channel = client.get_channel(channelIDS)
    await channel.send( embed = discord.Embed(description = f'Пользователь ``{member}`` наткнулся на наш сервер.', color = discord.Color.green()) )


@bot.event
async def on_member_remove( member ):
    channel = client.get_channel( channelIDS )
    await channel.send( embed = discord.Embed(description = f'Пользователь ``{member}`` покинул наш сервер.', color = discord.Color.green()) )
    await member.send( embed = discord.Embed(description = f'Пользователь ``{member}``покинул наш сервер.', color = discord.Color.green()) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Читайте [документацию](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=discord.Intents().all)
channelIDS = 812680242812420111

@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(channelIDS)
    await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=f'Пользователь {member} наткнулся на наш сервер.', color=discord.Color.green()))

@bot.event
async def on_member_remove(member):
    channel = client.get_channel(channelIDS)
    await channel.send(embed=discord.Embed(description=f'Пользователь {member} покинул наш сервер.', color=discord.Color.green()))
    await member.send(embed=discord.Embed(description = f'Пользователь {member}покинул наш сервер.', color=discord.Color.green()))
```

Comment: Теперь другая ошибка: 
TypeError: BotBase.__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'command_prefix'

Comment: Забыл указать префикс, `исправил`

Answer (score 0):

У вас лишь ошибка в том, что вы не правильно создали переменную `bot`... Вы пытаетесь использовать атрибут `Bot` к модулю `discord`, но там его нет, а есть он в `discord.ext.commands` и поэтому вы должны так сделать (и ещё, надо присвоить префикс, без него работать не будет):

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents = discord.Intents.all())
```

А остальной код весь правильный)